# I want to get the ways in which I can divide an array(or list) into two parts

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, set

I want to divide an array into two parts of any length.
eg. I have an `array=[1,2,3]`
now I need to find to subarrays every time I iterate.

```
xsub=[1],ysub=[2,3]
xsub=[2],ysub=[1,3]
xsub=[3],ysub=[1,2]
xsub=[1,2],ysub=[1]
```

and so on... total of 6 ways.

I tried doing this but had a problem when I had repeating values in an array
e.g. `[1,2,2,4,2]`

code

```
def printSubArrays(s):
x = len(s)
for i in range(1 << x):
....subarr.append ([s[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))])


if(pa==0 and len(subarr[x])+len(subarr[y])==len(arr) and 
len(subarr[x])!=0 and len(subarr[y])!=0):    
....print("running",subarr[x],subarr[y])
```

Please help me out, you can also make another code for the same or modify the existing one

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I'd suggest describing what your trying to do more carefully, adding some example inputs and outputs, and fixing the formatting of your code.

Comment: Your "solution" for [1,2,3] is incorrect; your last example has `[1,2]` and `[1]`.

Comment: the Python Library has a function that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def printSubArrays(s,print_all=0):
    x = len(s)
    subarr = []
    for i in range((1 << x)):

        include = []
        exclude = []
        for j in range(len(s)):

            if_include = (i & (1<<j))
            #print(if_include)
            if if_include == 0:
                include.append(s[j])
            else:
                exclude.append(s[j])


        if len(include)!=0 and len(exclude)!=0:
            subarr.append((include,exclude))

    return subarr 
printSubArrays([1,2,2,4,2])
```